# Share local variable value between barrier threads in java

Tags: java, concurrency, barrier, shared-variable

I've been working on implementing a custom **Cyclic Barrier** which adds values passed into the await method and returns the sum to all threads when after notify is called.

The code:

```
public class Barrier {

    private final int parties;
    private int partiesArrived = 0;

    private volatile int sum = 0;
    private volatile int oldSum = 0;

    public Barrier(int parties) {
        if (parties < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of parties has to be 1 or higher.");
        this.parties = parties;
    }

    public int getParties() { return parties; }

    public synchronized int waitBarrier(int value) throws InterruptedException {
        partiesArrived += 1;
        sum += value;
        if (partiesArrived != parties) {
            wait();
        }
        else {
            oldSum = sum;
            sum = 0;
            partiesArrived = 0;
            notifyAll();
        }
        return oldSum;
    }

    public int getNumberWaiting() { return partiesArrived; }
}
```

This works, but I hear that there is a way to change the values `sum` and `oldSum` (or at least `oldSum`) into local variables of the `waitBarrier` method. However, after racking my head over it, I don't see a way.

Is it possible and , if yes, how?

Comment: `oldSum`, sure. But how could `sum` be a local variable? Threads can't share local variables. How can the threads compute the sum if they don't share it with each other?

Comment: @SolomonSlow, can you elaborate on how ```oldSum``` can be made into a local variable?

Comment: Um,... remove the class-level declaration of `oldSum` and declare `int oldSum` inside the `waitBarrier(...)` function.

Comment: @SolomonSlow won't work. The sums won't be the same

Comment: Same as what? There is only one sum. You only use `oldSum` as temporary storage to hold it so that you can set `sum = 0` before returning its previous value.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `sum` and have the first party clear it:

```
public synchronized int waitBarrier(int value) throws InterruptedException {
    if (partiesArrived == 0) {
        sum = 0;
    }

    partiesArrived++;
    sum += value;

    if (partiesArrived == parties) {
        notifyAll();
    } else {
        while (partiesArrived < parties) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Note that the wait condition should always be checked in a loop in case of [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). Also, `sum` doesn't need to be `volatile` if it's not accessed outside the `synchronized` block.

Comment: What you said is true, but it does not answer the OP's question which was, "how could this work if `sum` was a local variable?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow *(or at least `oldSum`)*

Answer (score 0):

> However, after racking my head over it, I don't see a way.

Quite so.

> Is it possible and , if yes, how?

it is not possible.

For some proof:

Try marking a local var as `volatile`. It won't work: The compiler doesn't allow it. *Why* doesn't it? Because volatile is neccessarily a no-op: local vars **simply cannot be shared with another thread**.

One might think this is 'sharing' a local:

```
void test() {
   int aLocalVar = 10;
   Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
     System.out.println("Wow, we're sharing it! " + aLocalVar);
   });
   t.start();
}
```

But it's some syntax sugar tripping you up there: Actually (and you can confirm this with `javap -c -v` to show the bytecode that `javac` makes for this code), a *copy* of the local var is handed to the block here. This then explains why, in java, the above fails to compile *unless* the variable you're trying to share is either [A] marked `final` or [B] could have been so marked without error (this is called 'the variable is effectively final'). Had java allowed you to access non-(effectively) finals like this, and had java used the copy mechanism that is available, that would be incredibly confusing.

Of course, in java, all non-primitives are references. Pointers, in the parlance of some other languages. Thus, you can 'share' (not really, it'll be a copy) a local var and nevertheless get what you want (share state between 2 threads), because whilst you get a copy of the variable, the variable is just a pointer. It's like this: If I have a piece of paper and it is mine, but I can toss it in a photocopier and give you a copy too, we can't, seemingly, share state. Whatever I scratch on my paper won't magically appear on yours; it's not voodoo paper. But, if there is *an address to a house* on my paper and I copy it and hand you a copy, it feels like we're sharing that: If you walk over to the house and, I dunno, toss a brick through a window, and I walk over later, I can see it.

Many objects in java are immutable (impervious to bricks), and the primitives aren't references. One solution is to use the `AtomicX` family which are just simplistic wrappers around a primitive or reference, making them mutable:

```
AtomicInteger v = new AtomicInteger();
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {v.set(10);});
t.start();
t.yield();
System.out.println(t.get());
// prints 10
```

But no actual sharing of a local happened here. The thread got a -copy- of the reference to a single AtomicInteger instance that lives on the heap, and both threads ended up 'walking over to the house', here.